# How would I remove the gap between the image and the Bootstrap Nav bar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The carousel is not touching the navbar as you can see. I would like to remove the margin in between it. I've tried using negative margins, they don't seem to work. Anyone here that can help me? https://i.stack.imgur.com/1htJM.png

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AwakenNetwork</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href = "css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="wrap">

        <div class = "navbar navbar-default">
            <div class = "container">

                <a href = "#" class ="navbar-brand">AwakenNetwork</a>

                <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <div class ="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li class = "active"><a href = "#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></span> Forums</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></span> Vote</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower"></span> Staff</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> Rankings</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Store</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
         </div>           
      </div>

    <div style="height: 365px; background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/246mjb1z7mahfe2/img1.jpg'); position: relative">
      <div class="carousel-caption" style="bottom: 15px">
              <h1 style="font-size: 100pt">Awaken Network</h1>
              <h1>Be Awakened..</h1>
            </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `margin-bottom: 0` on the navbar?

Comment: your html doesnt seem to be valid for a start - you dont seem to be closing your divs correctly at the bottom of your html (maybe your code block is cut off however). There should be only 1 h1 tag also, but this would'nt be related to your problem

Comment: put a link or create a jsfiddle to see the problem. Your code is uncompleted.

Comment: yes seeing the CSS you are using is quite essential for debugging your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're doing it right, make sure you use

```
.navbar { margin-bottom:0px !important; }
.carousel-caption { margin-top:0px !important }
```

Answer (score 0):

margin: 0 on your nav ul:

HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

CSS

```
ul.nav{
  margin: 0;
}
```

(Or at least 0 on the margin-top)

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar { margin-bottom:0px !important; }
```

Comment: @alhwaiji-abdulaziz-n, While your code may correct as answer But Elaborating what your code does, It can improve the quality of your answer. Checkout the Article : [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)