# White space between navbar and jumbotron image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have referred to this question but to no avail: [How would I remove the gap between the image and the Bootstrap Nav bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975046/how-would-i-remove-the-gap-between-the-image-and-the-bootstrap-nav-bar)

Here's what I have so far.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills colour pull-right">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#" id="home"
             onmousedown="clickDown(this)"
             onmouseup="clickRelease(this)">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="resume.html" id="resume"
             onmousedown="clickDown(this)"
             onmouseup="clickRelease(this)">Resume</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="contact.html" id="contact"
             onmousedown="clickDown(this)"
             onmouseup="clickRelease(this)">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Software developer</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
    background-color: #536872;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.header {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.header h1 {
    background-image: url("../images/contact.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    line-height: 400px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Shouldn't the margin-bottom and margin-top attributes close the white gap?

[image]

Thanks for reading this.

EDIT: Solved this on my own. I added `<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">` to replace `<div class="nav">`

Comment: can you place your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: I guess the white gap should be a part of the `<div class="container"></div>` . Is there any css applied to the class `.container`?

Comment: The code looks really off on jsfiddle for some reason (I've never used this). I'd be glad to paste it in jsfiddle with some help.

Answer (score 1):

Its not white space from header
Its margin of h1 tag

```
<h1>Software developer</h1>
```

so add in style

```
h1{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add class .jumbotron in css and provide margin-bottom like this

```
.jumbotron
{
margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: This is old, but since there is no "correct answer" selected, I figured I would share that this works. Including the !important was the key. Technically, the op needed margin-top: 0px, but that is minor.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have a `margin-top` set to on your `.jumbotron` class. Just set it to 0 and it should close the gap.

An alternative reason could be that your image is not tall enough and you have `background-repeat` set to `no-repeat`.

Comment: I've tried it, but the gap remains. Also, I do not have `background-repeat` set to `no-repeat`.

Comment: Strange. Do you have any other css apart from bootstrap and the css on your question?

Comment: I have other CSS code that deals with the nav pills on the nav bar. Let me update my CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in CSS, it will remove the gap between navbar and image.

```
body { padding-top: 50px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the background color of your header to #eeeeee using CSS. This effectively closes the gap between the navbar and the jumbotron because the space between them is the same color as both elements.